# dynamic form submitting

Tags: php

I have in the form like

```
 <form action="sub.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username[]"><br>
    <input type="text" name="hometown[]"><br>
    <input type="text" name="country[]"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

sub.php

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
foreach($_POST['username'] AS $ID => $Value){

        echo "Checkbox with value ".$sValue." was checked!<br>";
    }
```

I could get only one one input field i.e., username
Can we get all 3inputs to sub.php

Comment: You want to loop through all posted values?  Just do a `foreach` over `$_POST`.

Comment: Where does `$_POST['user']` come from?  Why are those text inputs trying to be arrays?  There seems to be a number of typos or other unexplained things in your code.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @David - Ya the code was edited to username. THANKS!!!

Comment: what you get in var_dump($_POST) ??

Comment: @GBD Rightnow, Iam getting only username values to sub.php, but like wise I need for all inputs i.e., username[], hometown[] & country[] in the same foreach loop

Comment: @karthik why `username[]` is an array? Why not only `username`?

Comment: As I am using dynamic rows add, remove. When add, rows will add and remove the row. SO like wise I have total 5 rows for each 3 inputs

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question

```
 <form action="sub.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user[1][name]"><br>
    <input type="text" name="user[1][hometown]"><br>
    <input type="text" name="user[1][country]"><br>

    <input type="text" name="user[2][name]"><br>
    <input type="text" name="user[2][hometown]"><br>
    <input type="text" name="user[2][country]"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
$users = $_POST["user"];
foreach($users AS $ID => $info){
    echo "user $ID ({$info['name']}) lives in {$info['hometown']}<br>"; // dollar symbol added
}

echo "all usernames: ";
$all_ids = array_keys($users);
foreach($all_ids as $current_id) {
    echo $users[$current_id]['name']." ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is but there are a few issues with your html. It should be the following:

```
<form action="sub.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    <input type="text" name="hometown"><br>
    <input type="text" name="country"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit>
</form>
```

I removed the brackets from the fields because brackets normally imply that you want your php code to see it as an array of values but you have single text fields.

If you want to get all of the inputs from the form you should use:

```
foreach($_POST AS $ID => $Value){
    echo "Textbox with value ". $Value ." was used!<br>";
}
```

I changed it to textbox because your form doesn't have any checkboxes

Comment: No, I have a name for every input text like username[], hometown[], country[]

Comment: There are additional errors with the HTML, including not closing the tags.  (And not closing an attribute value, but that's been fixed in the original question.)

Comment: @David the question must have been fixed before I started my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this (not elegant but should show you where its going wrong..)

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
foreach($_POST['username'] AS $ID => $Value){

        echo "Checkbox with value ".$Value." was checked!<br>";
    }
$hometown = $_POST["hometown"];
foreach($_POST['hometown'] AS $ht_ID => $ht_Value){

        echo "Checkbox with value ".$ht_Value." was checked!<br>";
    }
$username = $_POST["country"];
foreach($_POST['country'] AS $c_ID => $c_Value){

        echo "Checkbox with value ".$c_Value." was checked!<br>";
    }
```

Comment: Ya the same logic I wanted but can we do everything in one foreach or while loop or any other way of getting all three inputs

Comment: no, you will need at least 2 foreach loops, one to go through the post, and the second to get the key=>values of each post, or if the keys are always the same, then you could foreach(POST as key => value) and target the know keys there - that way its one foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

If you have **equal # of username,hometown,country and in correct sequence**, then you can use following way

```
   foreach($_POST['username'] AS $ID => $Value){
        echo "Username ".$Value." was checked!<br>";
        echo "Hometown ".$_POST['hometown'][$ID]." was checked!<br>";
        echo "Country ".$_POST['country'][$ID]." was checked!<br>";
    }
```